Django Q cannot connect to mysql
I deploy my Django, Django-Q, mysql, metabase, redis on docker, but recently, I run the services and use simpleui to change admin page, but it shows the error as follow:
Traceback (most recent call last):
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
django_q           |     self.connect()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
django_q           |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
django_q           |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
django_q           |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 247, in get_new_connection
django_q           |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
django_q           |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
django_q           |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django_q           | MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to server on 'mysql' (115)")
django_q           |
django_q           | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django_q           |
django_q           | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_q           |   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
django_q           |     main()
django_q           |   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
django_q           |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
django_q           |     utility.execute()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
django_q           |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
django_q           |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in execute
django_q           |     self.check()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
django_q           |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
django_q           |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
django_q           |     return check_resolver(resolver)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
django_q           |     return check_method()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
django_q           |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
django_q           |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
django_q           |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
django_q           |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
django_q           |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
django_q           |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_q           |   File "/app/server/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
django_q           |     path('', include('kds.urls'))
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
django_q           |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
django_q           |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
django_q           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_q           |   File "/app/kds/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
django_q           |     from . import views
django_q           |   File "/app/kds/views.py", line 17, in <module>
django_q           |     from .tasks import open_reset, close_reset
django_q           |   File "/app/kds/tasks.py", line 97, in <module>
django_q           |     if not Schedule.objects.filter(func='kds.tasks.close_all_section').exists():
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1241, in exists
django_q           |     return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 598, in has_results
django_q           |     return compiler.has_results()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1530, in has_results
django_q           |     return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1560, in execute_sql
django_q           |     cursor = self.connection.cursor()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
django_q           |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
django_q           |     return self._cursor()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
django_q           |     self.ensure_connection()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
django_q           |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
django_q           |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
django_q           |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
django_q           |     self.connect()
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
django_q           |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
django_q           |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
django_q           |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 247, in get_new_connection
django_q           |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
django_q           |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
django_q           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
django_q           |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django_q           | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to server on 'mysql' (115)")

Obvious it is because of disconnection with mysql, but I don't know why my DRF service works and my client can get data from mysql via RESTful API, but my django-q service shows the disconnection error.
"settings.py" is as follow:
from pathlib import Path
import os
import socket

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-8(c-)h1d3#buf!14@6)w^n4sk&gkpa0ij2bc(1c)i1#868kwfc'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*']
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'simpleui',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'kds.apps.KdsConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_q',
    'django_filters',
    'gunicorn',
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

# Simpleui Configuration
SIMPLEUI_STATIC_OFFLINE = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'kds.middleware.GzipResponseMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'

# Caches settings
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://server-redis:6379/1',
    }
}

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'server.routing.application'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'kds_db',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'mysql',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

BASE_LOG_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "log")
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,  
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,  
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(threadName)s:%(thread)d] %(message)s'
        },
    },
# 过滤器
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],  # 只有在Django debug为True时才在屏幕打印日志
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',  #
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],  
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,  
        },
    },
}

# Django-Q
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'server', # project name
    'workers': 4, # number of workers. Default CPU cores
    'recycle': 500, # number of tasks before workers recycling memory
    'timeout': 60,
    'retry': 300,
    'compress': True, # data compression
    'cpu_affinity': 1, # the number of CPU the worker can use
    'save_limit': 250, # limitation on successful tasks
    'queue_limit': 500, # number of tasks in queue
    'label': 'Django Q',
    'redis': {
        'host': 'server-redis',
        'port': 6379,
        'db': 0,
    }
}

And my docker-compose.yml is as follow:
version: '3'
networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
  redis_network:
    driver: bridge
  django_network:
    driver: bridge
  web_network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      - redis_network
    container_name: server-redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    networks:
      - db_network
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --mysqlx=0
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_PORT=3307
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=kds_db
      - MYSQL_USER=***
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mysql
    ports:
      - 3300:8080
  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase
    networks:
      - db_network
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/metabase
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  django_q:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: python manage.py qcluster
    container_name: django_q
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - db_network
      - redis_network
      - django_network
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mysql
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: web
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 8 -k gthread && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - db_network
      - redis_network
      - django_network
      - nginx_network
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - django_q
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      -  ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - web_network
    depends_on:
      - web

Could someone tell me why it happen and how to solve it? I try to modify mysql configuration, but it doesn't work and cause my DRF connot access to mysql.

I suspect the environment variable setting MYSQL_PORT=3307 is causing the database to not listen on the standard MySQL port 3306; does deleting this help?  The networks: settings are far more complicated than they need to be, does the system work the same way if you delete all of the networks: blocks in the entire file?

Previously my project suffer a problem as my django cannot access mysql but I can access mysql via IP:port remotely. After adding those networks, my django can access mysql and provide RESTful service. You said they are too complicated, I don't know how networks influence it, could you explain? Many thanks

In Django settings.py file mention the database port as 3307. Because the docker internally runs the MySQL server in 3306 which was mentioned in docker-compose 3307:3306. For external connection you need to use 3307.

I know it, I can remotely access mysql via port 3307, and for container internal use, I should access via port 3306. But the problem is my DRF can access mysql, but django-q connot. Because they use the same database configuration in settings.py, that's why I feel confused about how to fix it.

I checked in the location of your CACHE settings, you added the db querystring as 1,
# Caches settings
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': 'redis://server-redis:6379/1',
   }
}

But in Q_CLUSTER settings you mentioned redis db as 0.
Q_CLUSTER = {
  'redis': {
      'host': 'server-redis',
      'port': 6379,
      'db': 0,
    }
}

Change your cache location to 0 like below & try it. I hope it'll help you.
# Caches settings
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': 'redis://server-redis:6379/0',
   }
}

